# Using Outlook, is there a way to create a Search Folder for specific people that I tag as my favorites?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

in Outlook I have dozens of people tagged as my "Favorites". Is there a way to create a search folder for just them so I don't miss any emails that get sent from them? Using the latest Outlook on Windows for O365.

Comment: Thank you @JW0914 - I was thinking Favorite PEOPLE not Favorite Folders but hopefully there is a solution with search folders so I could keep the emails where they are and just display them in 1 other spot...

Answer (score 1):

You may create a search folder for specific contacts this way:

- In the **Mail** view, select the email account you will create a search folder in, and click **Folder > New Search Folder**
- In the New Search Folder dialog, click "Mail from specific people"
- Click the **Choose** button and add your people
- Click **OK** twice to create the search folder.

Comment: Yes but to confirm, there isnt a way to do a Search Folder for contacts marked as Favorites right? So now I need to do manage both the search folder and the favorite list?

Comment: You can only use people from your address book.

Comment: Agree with harrymc, we can add the contacts marked as Favorites manually in Outlook.